Standard terminology for this type of ring morphism involving reduceness of rings
Here, "ring" = "commutative ring with 1" and "algebra" = "commutative algebra".
Let $R$ be a ring and $R'$ be an $R$-algebra with the following property: for every reduced $R$-algebra $S$ (i.e., $S$ is a reduced ring) one has that $S\otimes_RR'$ is also a reduced ring.
In my current research, the above type of algebra is beneficial. My question is: Is there some standard terminology for this kind of algebra? I mean, I already saw geometrically reduced algebras, but I am not convinced that they are the same (of course, the above algebras are geometrically reduced, but I am not convinced of the converse). Anyway, for a while I have been calling this "totally reduced $R$-algebra'', but I feel that I may be giving a name for a thing that was already named before. Thanks in advance.

You are saying that these algebras are of course geometrically reduced, but why is that? I mean you cannot apply the assumption to $S=R$ unless $R$ is reduced. The concept you define seems to be quite different from (geometric) reducedness, so I would also call it differently. A typical example is $R'=R[X]$, where $R$ can be anything.

When you translate the notion of geometrically reduced morphism of schemes to affine schemes you get the following:
Let $h:S\rightarrow T$ be a ring morphism. We say that $h$ is geometrically reduced if for every $\mathfrak{p}\in Spec S$ and $L$ a field extension of the residual field $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$, one has $(T\otimes_S\kappa(\mathfrak{p}))\otimes_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p})}L$ is reduced, i.e., $T\otimes_{S}L$ is reduced.
With this in mind, the implication I mentioned is clear once every field is reduced.
